# Using 2 style sheets on my website html

Tags: html, xhtml

I've finished my website and completed the style sheet but now i have created a second style sheet (called other.css). What I'm trying to do is have 2 links on my home page, one with "normal.css" and one with "other.css". So basically i want the user to be able to choose between my 2 styles. Ive duplicated all my original pages and added "2" to their name, i have also created other.css and referenced it on these pages. "2" pages all display the alternative layout fine but i dont know how to let the user switch between styles... any help please?

N.B. my html come isn't changing at all, i'm only changing the css file.

Dave

Comment: Are you using any specific server-side technology?

Comment: Show the html for your stylesheets links. Are you able to use JavaScript (because, for client-choice, I think you'll *need* to)?

Comment: no my website won't be going online, i'm just trying to teach myself. I have to links yet, just in the header i reference them...

Answer (score 0):

Good question. The answer would greatly depend on the server-side technology that you are using. For example, with Google App Engine which I usually use, it's a simple matter of changing part of the header of the HTML that is generated to point to a different CSS file. But then it's not a static HTML file.

[CSS Zen Garden](http://csszengarden.com) is specifically a website to illustrate the same HTML file presented with different stylesheets. Maybe you can get some ideas of how to do this from there. You'll see again though that the pages with different styles, even though they have the same HTML source, are not static .html pages.

Answer (score 0):

[This W3C page](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/alternatives.en.html) not only explains how to do it, but also has a number of alternate stylesheets itself, so you can actually test it in action.

In most browsers, the user can switch stylesheets with something like View → Page Style. All that's necessary is for the menu bar to be visible...

Answer (score 0):

If you have php on your server you could have the style sheet change based on a cookie. The following code would work:

```
if ($_COOKIE['style'] == '1') {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="normal.css" type="text/css" />';
}
elseif ($_COOKIE['style'] == '2') {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="other.css" type="text/css" />';
}
else {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="normal.css" type="text/css" />';
}
```

Add a link to the bottom of the page:
Change Style

On the changestyle.php page have the following:

```
if ((isset($_COOKIE['style'])) AND ($_COOKIE['style'] == '1')) {
setcookie(style,2) 
}
elseif ((isset($_COOKIE['style'])) AND ($_COOKIE['style'] == '2')) {
setcookie(style,1) 
}
else {
setcookie(style,2) 
}
```